# vscode javax.media cannot be resolved

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jogl

So I tried to use Java OpenGL in vscode, I already add the jar file in lib folder and add them in referenced libraries. However the library still cannot be imported.

[image]

Comment: What is the error prompt? Can you provide  jar packages to reproduce the problem?

Comment: You use JOGL 2 JARs with some source code based on JOGL 1, they use different package namespaces: https://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/index.html?overview-summary.html Replace "javax.media" by "com.jogamp". Moreover, keep in mind that Visual Studio Code has some limitations on Java projects especially if you use neither Gradle nor Maven; if your problem persists despite the package names fix, try another IDE, Eclipse Theia should do the job (it's the closest alternative I know).

Comment: By the way, JOGL specific problems should rather be dealt on our official forum: https://forum.jogamp.org/